# Regular expression to select 2 kinds of substrings

Tags: r, regex

I have strings like:

1. `\n A vs B \n`
2. `\n C vs D (EF) \n`
3. `\n GH ( I vs J) \n`

in a vector called `myData`.

The following is `myData`.

```
c("\n A vs B \n", "\n C vs D (EF) \n", "\n GH ( I vs J)\n")
```

I want to select `A vs B` from 1, `C vs D` from 2 and `I vs J` from 3.

I have the following code:

```
loc  = regexpr(".*vs.*|\\(.*vs.*\\)",myData,ignore.case=TRUE,perl=T)

end  = loc  + attr(loc,"match.length")-1

substr(myData,loc,end)
```

which gives three output:

```
[1] " A vs B " " C vs D (EF) " " GH ( I vs J)"
```

The last match is incorrect. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: I want to select A vs B from 1, C vs D from 2 and I vs J from 3.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "[A-Za-z]\\s*vs\\s*[A-Za-z]")
#[1] "A vs B" "C vs D" "I vs J"
```

---

Or if there are other lower case characters in place of 'vs'

```
str_extract(str1, "[A-Z]\\s*[a-z]+\\s*[A-Z]")
#[1] "A vs B" "C vs D" "I vs J"
```

---

Or with `sub` from `base R`

```
sub(".*([A-Z]\\s*[a-z]+\\s*[A-Z]).*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "A vs B" "C vs D" "I vs J"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("\n A vs B \n", "\n C vs D (EF) \n", "\n GH ( I vs J)\n")
```

Comment: Many thanks. I have items like "\n ABCD QWERTY vs EFGH \n" and also "\nABC (DEF vs JHI)\n".It's important to note that I want to capture a string entirely between \n and \n OR ( and ) , and it should have a vs somewhere in between.

Comment: @user2338823  But that was not in your original post.

Comment: @user2338823  No problem.  It is only because regex patterns are created based on a particular case.  the new pattern is completely different

Comment: @user2338823  Try `str_extract(str1, "[A-Za-z]+\\s*vs\\s*[A-Za-z]+")#
[1] "QWERTY vs EFGH"`.  It also works for `str1 <- "\nABC (DEF vs JHI)\n";
 str_extract(str1, "[A-Za-z]+\\s*vs\\s*[A-Za-z]+")#
[1] "DEF vs JHI"`

Comment: Many thanks. I finally chose this regex "(\n|\\()[^\n()]+vs[^\n()]+(\n|\\))"

Answer (score 2):

You may use the base R `regmatches` / `gregexpr` solution using a PCRE regex like yours, but using lookarounds, changing `.` to `[^()]` (to avoid the overflow across parentheses) and placing the longer alternative before the smaller one:

```
> myData <- c("\n A vs B \n", "\n C vs D (EF) \n", "\n GH ( I vs J)\n")
> res <- regmatches(myData, gregexpr("(?<=\\()[^()]*vs[^()]*(?=\\))|[^()]*vs[^()]*", myData, perl=TRUE))
> trimws(res)
[1] "A vs B" "C vs D" "I vs J"
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/UjvrAd)

**Details**:

- `(?<=\\()` - positive lookbehind making sure there is a `(` immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `vs` - a  literal substring
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `(?=\\))` - positive lookahead making sure there is a `)` immediately to the right of the current location
- `|` - or
- `[^()]*vs[^()]*` - a `vs` enclosed with 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`

**NOTE**: If you need to prevent the overflow across lines, you need to add `\r\n` to the `[^()]` -> `[^()\r\n]`.

See [**this regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yHzWBL/1).

Comment: Hello, this looks pretty close to what I want to do. May I ask where are you placing the longer alternative before the shorter one?

Comment: Because the longer one in a PCRE regex "wins", once the PCRE regex engine finds the matching alternatives (from the left) those remaining (on the right) are not even checked. If you want the longest alternative to match in an NFA regex (as PCRE), you need to place it to the left of the alternation group.

Comment: The longer alternative is the one AFTER the |. We 1st try to match the vs within ( ) and if we fail we then try the vs within the whole phrase.

Comment: @user2338823 No, the more specific pattern (and it is longer here) should come first in an unanchored NFA alternation-based regex. It works exactly as you specified.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening in case 3 here ?                                                                                               > res <- regmatches(myData, gregexpr("(?<=\\()[^()]*vs[^()]*(?=\\))|.*vs[^(]*", myData, perl=TRUE))
> res
[[1]]
[1] " A vs B \n"

[[2]]
[1] " C vs D "

[[3]]
[1] " GH ( I vs J)\n"

>

Comment: @user2338823: Could you please share via ideone.com? It is not quite clear what code you have in the comment. BTW, I see you use `.*vs[^(]*` as the second alternative. The `.*` is not a good choice because it will grab too much, and in case your string contains multiple matches, they risk landing in 1 single match due to it. Try `.*?`, lazy version.

Comment: Sure, maybe also see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2EoFlB/1). The lookbehind `(?<=\()` does not match at the start of the string -> regex engine goes to check the second alternative. `.*` does not match the first newline (PCRE regex does not match newlines with `.` by default). So, the first `\n` char is not matched. The regex engine goes on to check the space (2nd char). The lookbehind does not find `(` before the space, and then `.*` grabs the whole line up to the newline. Then the engine backracks, finds `vs`, and then `[^(]*` matches 0+ chars other than `(` returning `GH ( I vs J)\n`.

Comment: Are you saying that when there is a | (an OR between 2 patterns), at EACH character it matches the 1st pattern followed by the second pattern? I was under the impression that it would 1st check the WHOLE 1st pattern failing which it would check the whole 2nd pattern. I think that was incorrect.

Comment: This regex "(\n|\\()[^\n()]+vs[^\n()]+(\n|\\))" seems to be working and I can understand it. Is it the same as yours @Wiktor? I do not follow how backtracking works.

Comment: Backtracking is the mechanism allowing a regex go back to the pattern part where another matching path is possible if the current one fails to find a match. So, every part that is quantified (`*`, `{x,y}`, `+`, `?`), alternation groups, and even unanchored lookarounds may cause backtracking. `.+b` matches `aab` in `aabc` like this: `.+` grabs the whole `aabc` as `.` can match any char. Then there is still an obligatory `b` in the pattern and the engine wants to find it - but its index is at the end of the string! It *backtracks* and discards `c` as it is not `b`. Then `b` is found and matched.

Comment: @user2338823: I do not know why that regex works for you. It is almost an equivalent of [`[\n(]\K[^\n()]+vs[^\n()]+(?=[\n)])`](https://regex101.com/r/lNSisv/1) - you require a `(` or a newline at the start, then 1 or more chars other than newline and parentheses (greedy match, with backtracking), then `vs` and again any 1+ char other than `\n`, `(` and `)`, but followed with a `)` and `\n`. It works a bit differently, but **if that works for you the way you want it is great** although it is not what you asked for in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing a non-regex approach in the mix. Basically we split at `vs` and paste tha last character of the first element with the first character of the second element.

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ' vs '), function(i) 
                      paste0(substr(i[1], nchar(i), nchar(i)), ' Vs ', substr(i[2], 1, 1)))

#[1] "A Vs B" "C Vs D" "I Vs J"
```

Comment: I did not follow as to what's going on. Can you please explain?

Comment: Added an explanation.